# SEO problem for site with 2 domains

Tags: seo, duplicate-content, multiple-domains

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is duplicate content and how can I avoid being penalized for it on my site?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/35652/what-is-duplicate-content-and-how-can-i-avoid-being-penalized-for-it-on-my-site)

I have two domains pointing to the same site. I want both domains to co-exist, they share most of the same content, but they differ in design and they are aimed at different markets / rivaling communities.

Is there a way to let google know that these two domains are the same site and don't cause me to get hit with a duplicate content penalty? Any other general SEO tips for this situation would also be welcomed. Thanks.

Come on man, why was this closed. The linked page is completely irrelevant for me.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by two domains pointing to the same site. Are they forwarded in your registrar account or 301 redirected with .htaccess or some other method?

Comment: @Anagio they have the same A record.